# On AC4 it wont let me buy the last upgrade's for the Jackdaw, is this normal?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I have completed the game and yet it still wont let me buy the last upgrade's for the Jackdaw, why is this?

Comment: This sometimes happens to me on other games as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the final tier upgrades for the Jackdaw require you to have obtained a special plan for the upgrade before you can purchase them.

Comment: Sometimes I hate it when I need plans to buy something. What are you going to do with a plan?